New to Python, can't get a Github project working. can anyone help?
Trying to build the lyrics browser found here.
Although I have little to no experience with Python I've managed to get the software running on a Raspberry PI 2 to a point where the main program is auto-loaded but  udev rules file doesn't pass details of the USB drive to the main program when USB drive is inserted, so the display just shows "Insert USB media" on top bar and "Welcome" on bottom bar.
I don't think I'm far away and I've had to make some basic changes to the code to get this far.
I've followed instructions in the "Readme", changed the paths in lines 18 and 22 in the "udev rule"s file to reflect file structure of my Raspberry Pi.
I need the program to auto-mount a usb stick and pass the file structure to the main program.
The USB stick I'm using has been formatted and set up as per instructions and I can see it if I boot the Raspberry pi into Pi OS desktop.
Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Please [edit] your question and describe what you have done, explain what you need (what USB drive? Why is udev relevant?), and what changes you've already made.
